# How to jump to next frame actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a memory game here. And each time a card is removed from the gameboard I have "cardCount -2", when this cardCount gets to zero, I want the program to jump to the next frame which is like a "game over" page. I've tried using gotoAndStop(); as well as nextFrame(); but it doesn't seem to be working!

On my frame 1 I have the game, and on frame 2 I have the gameover page.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated! Thank you!

Here is my code!

```
package {
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.display.MovieClip;

public class MemoryGame extends Sprite{

    private var firstTile:cards;
    private var secondTile:cards;
    private var pauseTimer:Timer;
    private var levelTimer:Timer;
    private var score:int;
    private var cardCount:int;




    var numberDeck:Array = new Array(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6);


    public function MemoryGame(){
        score = 0;
        txtScore.text=": "+score;


        for(x=1; x<=4; x++) {
            for (y=1; y<=3; y++){
                var randomCard = Math.floor(Math.random()*numberDeck.length);
                var tile:cards = new cards();
                tile.card = numberDeck[randomCard];
                numberDeck.splice(randomCard,1);
                tile.gotoAndStop(9);
                tile.x = (x-1) * 150;
                tile.y = (y-1) * 200;
                tile.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,tileClicked);
                addChild(tile);
                cardCount = cardCount + 1

                if (cardCount == 0){
            trace("GAME OVER!")
            trace("SCORE:" +score);
        }


            }
        }
        trace("Cardcount: "+cardCount);
    }

    public function tileClicked(event:MouseEvent) {
        var clicked:cards = (event.currentTarget as cards);
        if (firstTile == null){
            firstTile = clicked;
            firstTile.gotoAndStop(clicked.card);
        }
        else if (secondTile == null && firstTile != clicked){
            secondTile = clicked;
            secondTile.gotoAndStop(clicked.card);
            if (firstTile.card == secondTile.card){
                pauseTimer = new Timer(1000, 1);
                pauseTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE,removeCards);
                pauseTimer.start();

            }
            else {
                pauseTimer = new Timer(1000, 1);
                pauseTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE,resetCards);
                pauseTimer.start();
            }
        }

    }

    public function resetCards(event:TimerEvent) {

        firstTile.gotoAndStop(9);
        secondTile.gotoAndStop(9);
        firstTile = null;
        secondTile = null;
        pauseTimer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE,resetCards);
        score = score - 2;
        txtScore.text=": "+score;
    }

    public function removeCards(event:TimerEvent){

        removeChild(firstTile);
        removeChild(secondTile);
        firstTile = null;
        secondTile = null;
        pauseTimer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE,removeCards);
        score = score + 10;
        txtScore.text=": "+score;
        cardCount = cardCount - 2;
        trace("Cardcount: " + cardCount);

        if (cardCount == 0){
            //NEXT FRAME CODE HERE!
            trace("GAME OVER!")
            trace("SCORE:" +score);
        }

                }


}
```

}

Comment: try `root.gotoAndStop(2);` or `MovieClip(this.parent).gotoAndStop(2);`or `MovieClip(this.parent.parent).gotoAndStop(2);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to extend `MemoryGame` from `MovieClip` , not from `Sprite`.

Comment: Is `MemoryGame` your main class?

Comment: Yes! It's all there in the code above. My entire code is there

Comment: Did you try `this.gotoAndStop(2);` when `if( cardCount==0 ){...}`?

Comment: 1061: Call to a possibly undefined method gotoAndStop through a reference with static type MemoryGame.

Comment: This is because, your `MemoryGame` still extends `Sprite`, not `MovieClip` !

Comment: if I extend MovieClip, it just flashes rapidly between the two frames

Comment: Add `stop();` at first frame or `this.gotoAndStop(1);` when your constructor begins.

Comment: Whoops forgot the stop() method!

Comment: So the core problem, was your `MemoryGame` was not of a `MovieClip` type. So you can accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your frame is on the main timeline, you need to call `stage.gotoAndStop(2);`.

Comment: I have tried this and receive the following error:

Call to a possibly undefined method gotoAndStop through a reference with static type flash.display:Stage

Comment: I have also tried event.target.parent.gotoAndStop(2) but it still doesn't work! I receive "ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property parent not found on flash.utils.Timer and there is no default value.
 at MemoryGame/removeCards()
 at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
 at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
 at flash.utils::Timer/tick()
"

Comment: Could you describe how you add your MemoryGame sprite to the stage?